# Google Sheets extract string between strings

Tags: google-sheets

So, I've imported emails to google sheets and I'm trying to extract some info.

e.g.: "Bla Bla Bla Ref: 338256 Clients: André Paulos, Beatriz Silva Thank you"
To retrieve the value of "Ref" I'm using: =ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"[\n\r].*Ref: \s*([^Clients]*)"))

If I use the same for extracting Clients' names, I get the results with a lot of missing characters. For the above example, it returns "André P".
(Using: =ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"[\n\r].*Clients: \s*([^Thank*)"))

What am I missing?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this helps

```
 =Arrayformula(if(len(A2:A), trim(regexextract(A2:A, "([^\:]*),")),))
```

or

```
=Arrayformula(if(len(A2:A), regexextract(A2:A, "Clients: (.*),")),))
```

Comment: The first one worked! I just had to change the first comma for "Thank". Thank you very much!